# Are companies in certain locations (big city vs small town, etc) more likely to offer telecommute contract programming work?

Tags: freelancing, telecommuting

I'm interested in taking on more contract projects for programming and, although it'd be nice to find clients just in my area, I want to expand my search a bit to other areas where a company may allow me to telecommute. I'm wondering if anyone who has experience with this has noticed that whether a company would be more likely to be open to this based on if they are in a bigger city vs a smaller town.

I would think that companies in smaller areas may have trouble finding programmers for some things and therefore would be more willing to outsource but maybe I am wrong. Any info is appreciated, I'm just trying to get an idea as to how to concentrate my efforts with networking with people form different areas, etc.

Comment: I think it's more about the size of the company than the size of the city they're in. I think you'll find smaller companies are more flexible, hiring freelancers rather than full time positions.

Comment: oh ok, that makes sense.. well I suppose smaller areas tend to have more small size companies :-) I guess the main reason is that I want to post a resume in some other areas rather than applying to a bunch of jobs

Answer (score 4):

I've done offsite programming contracts for 3M, Adobe, Apple, Kinko's, Microsoft, Motorola, and lots of folks you've probably never heard of, including an Oscar-winning special-effects firm, and a couple of artists who got a grant from the French government.

In my experience, willingness to use telecommuting contractors has nothing to do with a company's size or location, and everything to do with corporate culture and the personalities of the decision-makers. Some companies and managers are so risk-averse they'd rather not have work done at all than let somebody do it offsite.

Most of my telecommute contracts have come from companies in or near a big city; that's probably because that's where most people who need programming are. But you never know - I've also done contracts for folks in small towns in Illinois and Oregon.